# Apache TinkerPop allow duplicated Vertex ID

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

In this test we can see that it does not allow to insert the same vertex ID for the same datatype, but for different datatype it allows it.

- is this the expected behavior or a bug ?
- how can we know what is the Vertex ID data type after the Vertex was created ?

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.V()

# generate vertex id automatically by UUID.randomUUID()
gremlin> g.addV().property(id,UUID.randomUUID())
==>v[b47bb233-9a2a-49c8-8ada-0ac0fe9be6f2]
gremlin> g.V()
==>v[b47bb233-9a2a-49c8-8ada-0ac0fe9be6f2]

# generate vertex id manually as UUID datatype.
gremlin> g.addV().property(id,UUID.fromString("c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8"))
==>v[c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8]
gremlin> g.V()
==>v[c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8]
==>v[b47bb233-9a2a-49c8-8ada-0ac0fe9be6f2]

# generate vertex id manually as STRING datatype.
gremlin>  g.addV().property(id,"c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8")
==>v[c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8]
gremlin> g.V()
==>v[c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8]
==>v[b47bb233-9a2a-49c8-8ada-0ac0fe9be6f2]
==>v[c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8]

# here we can see the vertex with same id duplicated.
gremlin>  g.V().id()
==>c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8
==>b47bb233-9a2a-49c8-8ada-0ac0fe9be6f2
==>c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8

# trying to insert it again as UUID datatype.
gremlin> g.addV().property(id,UUID.fromString("c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8"))
Vertex with id already exists: c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8

# trying to insert it again as STRING datatype.
gremlin>  g.addV().property(id,"c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8")
Vertex with id already exists: c2d673de-2425-4b42-bc1e-68ff20e3b0a8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected behavior. You can do:

```
gremlin> g.V().project('id', 'class')
  .by(id())
  .by(map{it->it.get().id().getClass()})
==>[id:b6609a02-4574-4e6f-87ab-6ea3edaa9e55,class:class java.lang.String]
==>[id:b6609a02-4574-4e6f-87ab-6ea3edaa9e55,class:class java.util.UUID]
```

Apparently, comparing the String object and the UUID object always results in false.

By the way, the graph you opened is a TinkerGraph which is shipped with JanusGraph as part of Apache TinkerPop. JanusGraph itself does not allow vertex id's to be specified, unless explicitly configured that way.